# How to create a lookup dashboard page in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, importrange

I'm looking to create within Google Sheets a lookup sheet that pulls data from another sheet that is growing.

We are creating a sheet with all the information we are looking to track for people.

[Here's an example of what the input data could look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtJ1S.jpg)

Keep in mind that it's an ongoing thing, so that list will constantly grow.

I would like an additional sheet in the same document where it would be a dropdown box (or searchable field) of all the full names, and when you select one it will look up all the relevant information for that person.

[Here's an example of what the output data could look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQcKH.jpg)

The purpose behind this is that for a field worker who needs to quickly bring up information on a particular person, they should be able to have a sheet that quickly allows to get them the relevant information.

Building this within the confines of Sheets is a design constraint (the engineer in me wanted to build using other tools, but for a number of reasons we're staying purely with Sheets).

Any help would be awesome and appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To import data from another sheet you could use IMPORTRANGE, Google Apps Script or an add-on.

**References**

- [Import data sets and spreadsheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608?hl=en)